# What does the dot the in pytest command does?

Tags: python, pytest

I've suddenly discovered that all my projects in their CI run command have something like

`python -W ignore -m pytest --cov=source_dir --cov=another_dir . --reuse-db -s -v  --durations 10`

Whole this time I believed that the dot in the middle belongs to the coverage settings, but just realized that it does not! And it does not seem to make any difference as well, only slows the whole command down noticeably. Tried to read the pytest docs and google around but no results. Any ideas?

Comment: It's the base directory in which to look for tests. `.` is the current working directory.

Comment: @chepner That's pretty obvious:) I'll accept your answer if you create one.